# is it possible to display image view and text view on multiple rows without using List view in android?? i am using list view till now

Tags: android, android-layout

here i am inflating a layout into another layout having list view

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Certs>{

        Context context;
        public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,List<Certs> items){
            super(context, resourceId, items);
            this.context = context;

        }
         /*private view holder class*/
        public class ViewHolder {
            ImageView imageView;
            TextView makeText;
            ProgressBar mPB;    
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             //ViewHolder holder = null;



            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.makeText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_txtName);
                holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
                holder.mPB = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
                //holder.mPB.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFF4b86bb, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.DST);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            Certs currentCert = myCerts.get(position);

            holder.makeText.setText(currentCert.getName().toString());
            Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/calligraphic.ttf");
            holder.makeText.setTypeface(face);

            holder.imageView.setImageResource(currentCert.getIconID());


            //holder.mPB.setProgress(10);
            holder.mPB.setId(currentCert.getPbID());

            return convertView;
        }


    }
```

by this code i am able to inflate the layout but i dont want to use list view here.i want several images and text in different rows will show on same linear layout without using list view.

Comment: You can create a custom view by inflating a layout. Check here http://rajeshvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/03/inflating-ui-dynammically-example-in.html

Comment: ListView has its own properties of allocating and releasing views if they are not visible. If you don't use this and use your scenario of Linear layout, you may stuck with memory management.

Comment: Why don't you improve your item_view layout for your purpose?

Comment: aegean- Thanx for your suggestion ,but when i change my item_view layout i am able to show different strings in different line inside a <scroll view> but when i used to show different images on every line i got failed to achieve this.so please help me out with your relative suggestions.My motive is only to diplay these text and images

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible doing so.I have created related code like yours...

```
package com.android.customlayout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button mAddButton;
    private Button mDeleteButton;
    private LinearLayout mLinear;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        mDeleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        mLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.child_linear);
        mAddButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.add_button :
                View childView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
                mLinear.addView(childView);
                break;
            case R.id.delete_button :
                int childSize = mLinear.getChildCount();
                if(childSize != 0) {
                    mLinear.removeViewAt(childSize - 1);
                }
                break;
        }
    }  
}
```

And in your main xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
            android:text="Add" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/add_button"
            android:text="Delete" />

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/child_linear"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/add_button"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Make another xml named custom Layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this would help ..:)

Comment: Thanx for your answer but i am asking about image view with text view that can be scrollable without using listview because i am able to show different strings in different line inside a scroll view but when i used to show different images on every line i got failed to achieve this.so please help me out with your relative suggestions.Thank you

Comment: i have to set the strings and images dynamically using my custom adapter.

Comment: Arjun your problem is that images are not showing in list view. I'm right?.

Comment: Kirit Vaghela- yes,but when i am using scroll view in place of list view.I want to use text view with image view inside a scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

To load image in ImageView of listview than try following

**[Library for async image loading and caching on Android](https://github.com/novoda/ImageLoader)**